# SlimDX Device.Reset crashes with a "D3DERR_INVALIDCALL: Invalid call (-2005530516)" error

Tags: c#, .net, directx, slimdx

We recently upgraded from `VS 2005` to `VS 2008` (Windows XP). We use `SlimDx` in one of our projects. All was working ok after the upgrade, except my **Recover** function, which gets called on devicelost/device reset which crashes with

> D3DERR_INVALIDCALL: Invalid call (-2005530516)

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> and then <kbd>Escape</kbd> to simulate device lost.

```
void Recover()
{
  try
     {
         if (res.Code == D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET)
         { 
           res = m_device.Reset(m_presentParams); //Crashes on this.
           if (res.IsSuccess)
           {
             m_deviceLost = false; 
            }
          }
     }
   catch(Exception e)
   {}
 }
```

Is this something to do with `VS 2008`, as it used to work nicely with `VS 2005`?

Comment: Anything in the debug spew that helps you?

Comment: A quick search for "D3DERR_INVALIDCALL Reset" lead to MSDN.
"The method call is invalid. For example, a method's parameter may have an invalid value."

So my suggestion would be to check m_presentParams; does it contain the information you expect it to?

Comment: solved: some of the resources (stateblocks) were not disposed.

Comment: I had the same issue when using Axiom3D, a .NET implementation of Ogre that uses SlimDX for DirectX support.  Unsolved in my case...

Answer (score 9):

I found some helpful information in [this forum post](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=163751).  Note the question on that forum related to VB but this is still good info.  Full credit to [Simon O'Connor](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/profile.asp?mode=display&id=14005).

Reformatted and edited slightly.

> INVALIDCALL usually means that either a parameter you've passed to D3D is invalid or an operation you've requested isn't possible.
>
> The easiest way to find out why a D3D call returned an INVALIDCALL error is to let it tell you:
>
> 1. Make sure you're using the DEBUG version of the D3D runtime is installed (you were given the option when you installed the SDK).
> 2. Make sure that the DEBUG version of the runtime is enabled. Go to the DirectX applet in the Control Panel and look under the Direct3D tab.
> 3. Whilst in the DirectX control panel applet, increase the debug output level for Direct3D to maximum.
>      I've not used Visual BASIC for over 10 years so I've forgotten what debugging support is available and I don't have it installed on this machine to check... If VB DOES have a debug output window:
> 4. Run your program and let it fail with the INVALIDCALL error.
> 5. Now look at all the text in your debug output window. D3D will log information, warnings, and importantly errors to that. It'll also explain the reason WHY a D3D call has failed.
>
> If VB doesn't have a simple debug output window, download and run DebugView from http://www.sysinternals.com or use the command line debug viewer that comes with the DirectX SDK

Comment: dude, op solved the problem long time ago. See the comments ("some of the resources (stateblocks) were not disposed").

Comment: @SigTerm, yep, got that.  In my case it has nothing to do with stateblocks.  This is a generic error message, but this SO post has high google ranking for the error code, so I posed this answer in the hope that it might help someone else coming in via a search.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you didn't dispose all you resources (vertex buffer, texture, ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
void Recover() 
{ 
   try { 
            if (res.Code == D3DERR_DEVICENOTRESET) 
            { 
                 res = m_device.Reset(m_presentParams); //Crashes on this. 
                 if (res.IsSuccess) 
                 { 
                      m_deviceLost = false; 
                 } 
            } 
   } catch(Exception e) {} 
}
```