# D3DERR_INVALIDCALL: Invalid call (-2005530516)

Tags: c#, windows-xp, direct3d, slimdx

I seem to be getting an error when testing on my WinXP(SP3) PC. The error is below but I don't get it when using my Win7 laptop.

```
D3DERR_INVALIDCALL: Invalid call (-2005530516)
at SlimDX.Result.Throw[T](Object dataKey, Object dataValue)
at SlimDX.Result.Record[T](Int32 hr, Boolean failed, Object dataKey, Object dataValue)
at SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device..ctor(Direct3D direct3D, Int32 adapter, DeviceType deviceType, IntPtr     controlHandle, CreateFlags createFlags, PresentParameters[] presentParameters)
```

The code that is causes the error is:

```
using (var d3d = new Direct3D())
{
using (var tmpDevice = new Device(d3d, 0, DeviceType.Hardware, IntPtr.Zero, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, new PresentParameters() { BackBufferWidth = 1, BackBufferHeight = 1 }))
{
//I have some code here also but this doesn't even get here
}
}
```

As far as I'm aware the crash is to do with creating the new device.

Comment: Look at this link for some possible solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497641/slimdx-device-reset-crashes-with-a-d3derr-invalidcall-invalid-call-200553051

Comment: Ill give it ago, im downloading the SDK on my winXP system now so I can get some more debug information

Comment: sounds good.. I haven't used XP in a long time btw so I hope that helps

Comment: I personally don't use XP except for testing as many of my users still have XP systems.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "[C#][SlimDX][WinXP]" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Still having this issue, and even with the error output on high, this is all I get :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your graphics card probably doesn't support a 1x1 backbuffer.

Take a look at the output from the debug runtimes. Whenever you get an InvalidCall chances are good that there's some sort of diagnostic information there indicating what you did wrong.