# SlimDX When Game WindowFullmode Throw Error

Tags: c#, slimdx

DxScreenCapture.cs

```
 public class DxScreenCapture
    {
        Device d;

        public DxScreenCapture()
        {
            PresentParameters present_params = new PresentParameters();
            present_params.Windowed = true;
            present_params.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            d = new Device(new Direct3D(), 0, DeviceType.Hardware, IntPtr.Zero, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, present_params);
        }

        public Surface CaptureScreen()
        {
            Surface s = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(d, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Scratch);
            d.GetFrontBufferData(0, s);
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Capture Image and Serialize to Send Server

```
 using (Surface s = cap.CaptureScreen())
            {

                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
               Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.ToStream(s, SlimDX.Direct3D9.ImageFileFormat.Bmp));

                ns = client.GetStream();
                bf.Serialize(ns, bitmap); // ns = NetworkStream
            }
```

When Game Not Running state Works Great.
but Game running on full window mode
Throws Excpetion

```
SlimDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D9Exception
```

And this is the Inner exception:

```
D3DERR_INVALIDCALL: Invalid call (-2005530516)
```

[Excpetion Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If9EP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9550396/2263683) fits your problem as well

> My guess is that your graphics card probably doesn't support a 1x1
>   backbuffer.
>
> Take a look at the output from the debug runtimes. Whenever you get an
>   InvalidCall chances are good that there's some sort of diagnostic
>   information there indicating what you did wrong.

Comment: thanks you i will try run another Computer.. then.. how solve this problem?